# Forcing windows Phone to use WIFI connection

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

How to force windows phone to use wifi.  The issue is that when i connected to Zune, it is using the local machines Ethernet connection. I need to disable this through code. How i can achieve this in  windows phone 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The best thing to do is to disconnect the USB cable because the phone will still think that it is connected (it is still able to ping Zune and does not receive the same network connection changed events)

This makes it impossible to debug so I resolved to add logging to my DEBUG builds.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tell the phone which connection to use.

I've previously debugged this by connecting the device/phone to the PC but then disconnecting the PC from the internet.
That should get you what you're after.

Answer (score -1):

Try by closing the Zune.exe in desktop (or laptop) and run **WPConnect.exe**
And then try to debug.

Normally in x86 system **WPConnect.exe** resides in

> **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\WPConnect\x86**

path or in 64bit system it will be in the x64 folder.

Comment: How is this going to enforce Wifi?

Comment: Normally zune process helps to access the network for the device, disconnecting zune may help. It just my thought, if it helps that well and good.