# Forcing app to use 3G connection over wi-fi connection in WP7.5

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, wifi, windows-phone-7.1, 3g

I have an app in which as soon as user launches the app and ACCEPTS the EULA then the registration process starts, and to finish the registration process to obtain the user_id the app has to hit 3 servers.The first server has connection must happen through 3G even if wi-fi is available the user gets a message to disable Wi-Fi and connect only to 3g network to continue the registration. All the code is in place and the app works fine too. But the new requirement is to ignore the wi-fi and use only 3G so that the user is not disturbed with the message which will need the settings of the phone to be changed.

I went through many forum posts but nothing helped. I found  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075785/forcing-windows-phone-to-use-wifi-connection) and thought i could refer it to use according to my need. But did not help.

Then I found this:-

```
ConnectState.Disconnected
```

But i dunno whether i can use this to disable wi-fi till the 1st request is made then enable wi-fi after that.

Please help.

Thank You

Comment: You are not going to be able to "disconnect" the phones 3G connection through code.  They might not even have a WiFi connection, but my advice is to attempt to connect to the WiFi connection if it exists, problem solved since the WiFi connection will be given priority.

Comment: what i want is the vice versa of what you are telling.. i wan only 3g at one particular time. If both 3G and WI-Fi are on how will i use only 3G? is it even possible to force my app to do so?

Comment: I blame the way the question was written for my confusion.  My answer is the same, you are not going to be able to force a user to use their 3G connection, that is entirely up to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, why I unmarked the previous post as not answer was, I found a way to force my app to use 3G network connection over Wi-Fi, and the best part is, its going to happen only in the Application level and not device level. And of course the user will be notified that for registration purpose we will be using the 3G network. Here is the code.

In my httpconnection class post() method. am doing the following before initiating the request.

```
   HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
//the network preference depends on the requestID
            if (requestId == DataManager.REQ_REGISTRATION)
            {
                myHttpWebRequest1.SetNetworkPreference(NetworkSelectionCharacteristics.Cellular);
            }
            else
            {
                myHttpWebRequest1.SetNetworkPreference(NetworkSelectionCharacteristics.NonCellular);
            }
```

As simple as that. In other scenarios(not in my requirement) where 3G is not mandatory but preferred, the application tries to connect through 3G but if that fails it will automatically (without user's interference) connect through the available network.

Thanks to Steve for the knowledge he shared.
I hope this helps other ppl with similar requirements.

Comment: I just took a look at the msdn documentation and you are totally right. The SetNetworkPreference() method for the HttpWebRequest class came with Windows Phone 7.1 - thanks for pointing out, might be interesting for others :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Not possible with Windows Phone.
As a reason, an app should not be able to do something that the user didn't explicitly allow. When there is Wi-Fi, a connection over 3g isn't desired most of the time. Those data plans my be high-priced and the user doesn't expect an app using it when he has Wi-Fi enabled. So he has to disable Wi-Fi himself to keep full control.

Just curious: why is connecting via 3g so important for this specific server??

---

**Update**: As noted in another answer, there came a new Method SetNetworkPreference() of the HttpWebRequest-class with the Windows Phone 7.1 SDK. So, it is indeed possible, sorry about my misinformation.

Comment: Thats the way the client wants it to happen. I suppose they are trying to get the Subscriber.